# How to upload a folder and subfolders within documents using Alfresco Rest API?

Tags: rest, api, metadata, alfresco

I want to upload a folder that contains many subfolders, those subfolders contains also many documents, into alfresco repository. I did this with Bulk Import Tool using for each folder/document an xml metadata file for importing also their properties. But to do this I must generate for each an xml file containing the metadata. So I search for an alternative solution and I found that I can do this with Alfresco Rest API calls without that xml metadata file. But I really don't know how to use it for upload.

Please if someone can help me with that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, what have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Thank you for reply Jeff. So my goal is to export folders/documents from an app server to Alfresco's server. I tried the Bulk Import service and I succeed to do this programmtically using cURL command in Java classe. The problem is the metadata file for each folder/document that I must generate if I want to use this method. So I'm searching if there is a way with Alfresco Rest API to do the manipulation I said before without need to generate an xml file that contains metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get your files moved to the same server where Alfresco is running, using the Bulk File System Import Tool (BFSIT) is likely going to be the best import approach in terms of performance, even if you have to create the XML manifest files that describe the metadata that accompanies each file you are importing.

If that approach does not meet your needs you can use a variety of alternatives to do the import. That includes:

1. Writing a client that leverages CMIS using Java, Python, .NET, or any other languages for which you can find a CMIS client library. [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org) has several, but there are others out there.
2. Using the client-side JavaScript API that is shipped as part of ADF.
3. Using the Alfresco public REST API. Prior to Alfresco 5.2, the "Alfresco API" was a mix of CMIS and Alfresco-specific REST calls that handled things the CMIS API did not cover. With 5.2 there is a new set of RESTful endpoints that can be used for all sorts of things, including [creating nodes](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/createNode).

Defintely recommend taking a look at the [API Explorer](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com) to see the Swagger doc on the API.

Comment: I tried the Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS, the problem with that method, it becomes more complex in developing, if you have multiple subfolders in app server. For that, I'm searching for an easy way to do the export, using the BFSIT lets me upload in alfresco folders and subfolders at the same time. If is it the best approach, there is also another problem, for example, if I add/modify a folder/document in the app server it must also be added/modified in Alfresco.

Comment: The idea is to develop some kind of a synchronize connector using a Daily Timer between the two servers. Bulk Import service export also the folders/documents even if they aren't changed, which will take more time for what is already exists. For the Alfresco API, I really don't know how to do the same manipulation, that I did using BFSIT, with it. I tried GET/POST calls, but something like export from a sourceDirectory (my app server) and upload it to a targetPath (alfresco) like BFSIT, I didn't found it. Thanks a lot Jeff.

Comment: There are a number of approaches you could take. For example, you could use a cron job that fires off a script that leverages CMIS. You could use Apache Camel to monitor a directory and then it could use CMIS to move the file(s) into Alfresco. You could use a queue based approach, see https://www.slideshare.net/jpotts/moving-gigantic-files-into-and-out-of-the-alfresco-repository. You could map the directory to Alfresco via WebDAV. Really, it's up to you and your specific requirements. If you try any of these approaches and get stuck, feel free to create a new post and maybe someone can help.

Comment: You really clarify the path to follow to me. Thanks a lot Mr Jeff.

Comment: The following presentation from the last Alfresco DevCon can give you some ideas too:
https://www.slideshare.net/PiergiorgioLucidi/smart-content-migration-using-apache-manifoldcf-output-connectors/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOWAxrhuazk